# How to run Flink job with savepoint in remote environment?

Tags: apache-flink

When use Flink remote environment，how to run job with savepoint?I can't find any api to apply.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ClusterClient#run(JobWithJars, int, SavepointRestoreSettings)](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/api/java/org/apache/flink/client/program/ClusterClient.html#run-org.apache.flink.client.program.JobWithJars-int-org.apache.flink.runtime.jobgraph.SavepointRestoreSettings-).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this command:

```
$ bin/flink run -s :savepointPath [:runArgs]
```

See [docs](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.5/ops/state/savepoints.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In order to run a job from a savepoint via a remote environment, you should initialize a remote environment with specified savepoint restore settings, i.e.:

```java
SavepointRestoreSettings savepointRestoreSettings = SavepointRestoreSettings.forPath("/tmp/savepoints/savepoint-342c17", false, RestoreMode.CLAIM);
env = new RemoteStreamEnvironment(remoteHost, remotePort, Configuration.fromMap(Map.of()), new String[] {}, null, savepointRestoreSettings);
StreamTableEnvironment.create(env, settings);
```

Note, that this is a bit different from using a Rest API (https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/ops/rest_api/#jars-jarid-run), since in this case, the savepoint path is the path to a file from a local machine that submits the job to remote, not the savepoint path on a remote cluster.

In other words, using Rest API approach, you submit job params to remote, but the job graph is built on a remote cluster. In case of a remote environment, you are building a job graph on a client and submitting an already built job graph via rpc, so you have to read a savepoint on a client.